Upcoming Moderator Election
As a few people have noticed, we are down a moderator:  quid has been inactive for a while, hence their moderator status has been suspended in accordance with the process outlined on the main Meta site.  Our understanding is that quid has become quite busy with real-world stuff.  If quid ever finds the time to return to moderating on Math SE, we would welcome them back but, in the meantime, we are a person short.
As such, we will be holding another round of moderator elections.  The next Math SE moderator election will commence on Tuesday, 30 July.  As usual, the election will be announced and conducted on Math Meta.

The link to the election is already active

You say that the election starts on July 30, but on https://math.stackexchange.com/election/10 it is said that nominations begins on August 6 (and the elections begins on August 13).

@MartinR Just to clarify: the question collection process (part of the election cycle) starts on 30 July so that when nominations open the week after candidates will know which questions to address in their statements.
